# SQL Azure - Script Automated Export Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure allows for the Automated Export on a scheduled basis to Azure blob storage.  This can be configured in the Azure Management Portal on a per database basis.

Is there a way to script this via powershell, REST API or the Windows Azure Management Libraries?

We are developing a sharded database solution with more than 60 shards per environment, which means 100s of databases to configure, doing this manually isn't really an option.

Answer (score 1):

You have a PowerShell Cmdlet - **Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport** - [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn546720.aspx), using that you can start an export of SQL Azure Data to Blob Storage.

You can use that cmdlet in PowerShell Scheduled Job - [Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849759.aspx)

You can create a VM Role and run your custom PS script in it. So that All your PS operations will be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but [Sandrino Di Mattia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384546/sandrino-di-mattia) wrote about this [here](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/backup-and-restore-your-sql-azure-database-using-powershell/) -

```
param([string]$ConnectionString = $(throw "The ConnectionString parameter is required."), 
      [string]$DatabaseName = $(throw "The DatabaseName parameter is required."),
      [string]$OutputFile = $(throw "The OutputFile parameter is required."), 
      [string]$SqlInstallationFolder = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server")

# Load DAC assembly.
$DacAssembly = "$SqlInstallationFolder\110\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
Write-Host "Loading Dac Assembly: $DacAssembly"
Add-Type -Path $DacAssembly
Write-Host "Dac Assembly loaded."

# Initialize Dac service.
$now = $(Get-Date).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
$Services = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $ConnectionString
if ($Services -eq $null)
{
    exit
}

# Start the actual export.
Write-Host "Starting backup at $DatabaseName at $now"
$Watch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.StopWatch
$Watch.Start()
$Services.ExportBacpac($OutputFile, $DatabaseName)
$Watch.Stop()
Write-Host "Backup completed in" $Watch.Elapsed.ToString()
```

Comment: Sorry but I've seen that, this allows you to execute an export that is initiated locally, what I am looking to do is configure the Automated Export which takes place solely in the Azure data center. A discussed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql-bi-sap-cloud-crm_all_in_one_place/archive/2013/07/24/sql-azure-automated-database-export.aspx)